# Redirecting IIS website to Apache website

Tags: apache, tomcat, iis

I have IIS 7.5 and a website which currently running.  I also have build a new website on WordPress running on Linux container published by Apache Tomcat.

I need to redirect the old websiteURL which is hosted on the ISS to the new site on WordPress. 
Is this possible ? I have tried http redirect, but this only works locally since the new website isn't published to outside.

Comment: What do you mean by not being published? Do you want the content to be loaded from Tomcat and be served by the IIS?

Comment: Website on the tomcat is only local I have renamed the IP to URL through my DNS, what I mean is the wordpress is only local host. I need the ISS to redirected to my word press locally hosted website

Comment: I tried to put another possible solution as answer. But it will work only if IIS has visibility of your local machine. e.g. you can ping your local machine from the IIS box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that Http Redirect should be the solution. 
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect?showTreeNavigation=true

if your Apache website is 'not published', I guess it will not be visible for Internet users including the IIS box. This means there won't be any way of serving your content from the Apache box.

If you are in a setup that the IIS has visibility of the Apache, but general Internet does not, then you might have a solution. This scenario can exist because of certain firewall rules. In this situation, you can set up what is called a 'Reverse Proxy' in IIS.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/

Comment: I did configured the Reverse Proxy, its does work, but there is an issue which is it doesn't show the complete page it's definitely partial view. there is not design. just markups. any idea?

Comment: I guess your CSS files are not getting loaded. They are probably getting served differently from your Markup. I suggest look at your network traffic in the browser to see if you get a clue. i.e. hit F12 on your Chrome browser and look at the Network tab and look for errors

Comment: Thank you for you help your suggestion worked, I inspected the elements and went to network tab,I found my display/layout contents are under the local IP address as domain of the server that runs the site. Changing the link directories of the contents on the word-press control panel matching to the url I have configured the reverse proxy the issue resolved and working